# android data sharing in a building

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play-services, wifi-direct

I have some questions on android data sharing of multiple devices. Currently, I have a personal project on android application which require multiple device can sharing data offline. You can look at the photo to get more understand about this. 
[View Image Here](http://i60.tinypic.com/ebctns.jpg)

I have a **device A** running my application which it use for entry data in one activity (entry activity)  and **device B** running the same application which use other activity (result activity). I want the data from **device A** can be send to **device B** without internet connection.

For example, when **device A** entry data and save it. **Device B** will receive that data. Both devices are in difference room which quite hard to connect via Bluetooth. Both devices do not have NFC.
Does anybody have the idea of this requirement?

Can you give me some advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html. This might fit your needs. Sample data is also provided there.